# How to addError on the dynamic string field api name

Tags: apex

```
 obj.get(childFieldAPIName).addError('Required');
```

Error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(String) from the type Object

I am trying to add the error on the fields which are in String format "childFieldAPIName" but it is not allowing.

Something like this 
        `genericObj.get('fieldname').addError('myString');`

Comment: As the error says, `Object` does not have the method `get()`. You can only call this on `sObject` instances. Would you please [edit] your question to provide more code context for what you are doing?

Comment: Thanks, @david I am trying to add an error message on the fields of Standard detail page using the .addError method and I have the fields in the String format with API Name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do, but there's another error getting in the way first. In this expression:

```
obj.get(childFieldAPIName).addError('Required');
```

the error

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(String) from the type Object

is telling you that you can't call `get()` on a generic `Object` value. You can only call this method on an `sObject` instance or concrete subclass.

If you had an sObject, such as doing something like this:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert) {
    sObject q = Trigger.new[0];

    ((String)q.get('Name')).addError('Bad');
}
```

you'd get back

> addError must be invoked on an expression that is an exact SObject field reference

If you don't cast the return value to a `String`, you'll just get the generic error

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void addError(String) from the type Object

The upshot is that if you want to associate an error with a field, you need to reference it explicitly and via one of the special sObject instances that are part of your trigger context variables, as for instance

```
Trigger.new[i].Name.addError('Bad value');
```

You *cannot* call `addError()` on sObject instances that aren't part of the trigger context variables, including query results and instances of other sObjects than those being processed by the trigger (such as child or parent objects). It will have no effect in those situations.

Comment: +1 Also, [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000GoC5AAK).